# Execute command in script based on year

Tags: macos, bash, shell, datetime, scripting

I have a Powerbook with a dead laptop battery... Everytime I disconnect it from it's power source the date gets set back to the year 1969. This leads to some issues with network authentication, keychain access, etc. I wrote a launch daemon that executes this script in order to set the date to something more appropriate at boot, which works fantastically.

```
  #!/bin/bash

  date 0101122014
```

Now I only want it to only run if the year is 1969, that way if the time is correct it won't get set back at all.

so something like...

```
  #!/bin/bash

  YEAR="date +%Y"

  if [ $YEAR = 1969 ] ;
  then date  010112002014 
  else exit 0
  fi
```

I know the syntax is totally off, it's just to give an idea of what I want to do. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: I know I'm close I just need the last little bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [command substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution):

```
YEAR=$(date +%Y)
```

Or even:

```
[ $(date +%Y) = 1969 ] && date 010112002014
```

Or, using an `if`:

```
if [ $(date +%Y) = 1969 ]
then date 010112002014
fi
```

Comment: could you show me using a if, then else statement, but keep that example too?

Comment: You want to use `-eq` instead of `=` here.

Comment: @l0b0: No, I don't — I could use it, but I don't want to use it.  1969 is a perfectly good string, as well as being a perfectly good number.  A string comparison is fine; a numeric comparison would also work.

Comment: Note that this answers the direct question — how to fix the shell script.  It doesn't answer the indirect question: is this the best way to set the system clock.  The fixed time in 2014 is better than nothing, but is not ideal.  I've not run NTP when the system clock said 1969 and the current time is 2014.  Have you considered getting the RTC battery replaced?

Comment: Thanks a lot man. I'm also glad to know how close I was. If it wasn't for people like you I wouldn't know squat about this. -eq only works with integers right?

Comment: I have actually but it's a lil difficult, requires some soldering. Getting a new laptop battery will also fix it and I'm saving some $ for that. I also wrote a script to update the time via ntp every 3 minutes, but if the date gets set that far back it has issues connecting to internet period.

Comment: Yes, the `-eq` operator only works on integers, but the arguments to the test command are strings first and only integers after they're converted to integers.  As I said, numeric comparison would work; the output from `date +%Y` is a string that can be interpreted as an integer, and 1969 in this context is a string that can be interpreted as an integer, so everything is happy.  But they're also both perfectly good strings, and a string comparison for equality works sanely (but less than or greater than would be problematic; you need to do a numeric comparison then).

Answer (score 3):

Execute this command to set the date:

```
sudo ntpdate -u time.apple.com
```

`ntpdate` will query the specified time server for the current date/time and then update the local time.

Note: The error in your script is `YEAR="date +%Y"`: that just assigns the string `date +%Y` to `YEAR`. But you want to execute `date +%Y` and assign the result:

```
YEAR=$(date +%Y)
```

Related:

- [Set the System Time in Mac OS X from the Command Line](http://osxdaily.com/2012/07/04/set-system-time-mac-os-x-command-line/)

Comment: Excellent - solves the problem rather than using a flawed workaround.

Comment: I'm using a launchdaemon to update the time via ntp every 3 minutes :) problem is I lose my ability to automatically connect to internet if date is set to 1969 at login. It's not a flawed workaround it's part of a temporary solution until I get a new battery. it's also designed to not interfere if my date is already correct :) Thanks for all the help guys. Love yuh.

Comment: I suggest that you save the current date in a file when you shut down and restore it from that file when you boot. That way, the initial offset will be small.

Comment: I actually thought of that too since my computer is only off for hours at a time, but thought it would be too difficult. Wanna show an example of how that would work?

Comment: This may help: http://superuser.com/questions/245713/whats-the-easiest-way-to-have-a-script-run-at-boot-time-in-os-x

Answer (score 2):

Another approach

```
#!/bin/bash

monfile="/tmp/.com.example.touchfile"

#if have OK (current) date set the file modification time
have_current_date() {
        date > "$monfile"
}

#set the date from the last file modification time
have_wrong_date() {
        [ -f "$monfile" ] || touch -t 201401010101 "$monfile"
        eval $(stat -s "$monfile")   #get the file modification time to shell variable
        date -f '%s' $st_mtime   #set the date to "last" file modification time
}

#main program
YEAR=$(date +%Y)
case "$YEAR" in
        2014) have_current_date ;;      
        *) have_wrong_date ;;
esac
```

what is doing

- get the actual system date
- if the year is 2014 - touch the `$monfile` - set the file modification time to current time
- if the year isn't 2014 get the "last" file modification time and set the system date from it

Comment: Would this save the date & time to file then restore it?

Comment: @Geofferey yes, it stores the date in a file-attribute called as `last file modification time` or `mtime`.

Answer (score 1):

simple one using `if` :

```
if [ $(date +%Y) = 1969 ]
then date 010112002014
else exit 0
fi
```

Comment: I think your answer would be better if you ran the `date` command instead of echoing OK.

Answer (score 0):

So I got everything setup with your guys help & it works great. I used one script and a launch daemon to set, save & set time via ntp. Here they are :) There are a million ways to skin a cat this is how I skinned mine.

Heres the script:

```
#!/bin/bash


#Load variables from .conf file 

. /usr/share/fixes/time/time.conf


#Variables

DATE=$(date +%m%d%H%M%Y)


#Check year & set time from variable in .conf file

[ $(date +%Y) = 1969 ] && date $TIME


#Update time via ntp server

ntpdate -u $(systemsetup -getnetworktimeserver|awk '{print $4}')


#Save time to variable in .conf file 

sed -i -e "s/^TIME=.*/TIME=$DATE/" /usr/share/fixes/time/time.conf


exit 0
```

& launch daemon .plist for OSX which runs script every 3 minutes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.fix.settime</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>./usr/share/fixes/time/time-fix.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>180</integer>
</dict>
```

Thank you to all those that helped, I really appreciate it and feel I have learned something from all of you once again.